# How to install a plugin from github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

I have tryed to run this code in my console:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/apotonick/cells.git
```

...but i only get an empty folder named "cells" in my "vendor/plugins" dir.
What's wrong?

Comment: don't you get errors when trying to install the plugin? i tried here and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you Git version.
This may be related with you `gitconfig` file, as [described in this thread](https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/3743-scriptplugin-install-gitwhatever-does-nothing#ticket-3743-9)

> The reason is that it appears `rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/plugin.rb` is trying use git pull to grab the plugin code (see the install_using_git method), which doesn't work right.
>   Example:

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/fesplugas/typus.git
mkdir vendor/plugins/typus
cd vendor/plugins/typus
git init
git pull --depth 1 git://github.com/fesplugas/typus.git
```

> That last line exits 1, but that error is being masked by the `install_using_git` method, and the directory is just `rm -rf`'ed.
>
> I tracked this down to a conflict with `~/.gitconfig`. If I remove these lines it works:

```
 [branch "master"]
   remote = origin
   merge = refs/heads/master
```

> It appears a naked git pull has problems with these settings.

Actually, the problem would be here because of a *global* git config file (in your homedir: '`~/.gitconfig`'), defining a master which may be incompatible with the master expected by the `git pull` within that specific Git repo.

Comment: when I do:
"git --version" i get: "Unknown command 'git --version'. Type 'help' to show the list of available commands."

Comment: @Totty: that means either that Git is not installed, or that it is not added to your `$PATH`

Comment: thats the problem, i dont really understand what is all this git stuff, i went to their site, but i still dont get it :s

Comment: @Totty: the first issue to solve is your Git installation. Can you make sure you have it properly installed? On which OS are you using it?